# About executable files

Tags: rosmake, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm the new one to ROS.. I have written two cpp file named talker.cpp and listener.cpp in src and i add two lines seeing below in CMakeLists.txt file

```
rosbuild_add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp)
rosbuild_add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)
```

now when i give a command $make
it displays

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Would you please explain me clearly the steps which we need to execute cpp files  in ROS environment please explain it me in steps

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51609/about-executable-files/) by [Abinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3901/abinaya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-07

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3901/abinaya/) on 2013-01-07**:
please explain in me in steps clearly i'm very new to ROS

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2013-01-07**:
Please read the [support guidelines](http://ros.org/wiki/Support) before posting. Always tag your posts and provide enough information for us to reproduce the issue. Which exact steps did you follow? Which ROS and Ubuntu versions are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To run make you need a file called makefile. This tutorial tells you steps of how to create a package, including all necessary files:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage

Else you can use this as a Makefile:

```
include $(shell rospack find mk)/cmake.mk
```

This are instructions for ROS fuerte.

EDIT:
I am serious: Do the tutorial linked above. Your source files need to go into the src folder, you need a Makefile, and only when you have that Makefile will you get executables in the bin folder. The tutorial explains all that.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2